# Scala , what does this function definition means?

Tags: scala

In the following code snippet, what does   **(F: => T)**  mean?

```
def func1[T](arg1: Int, arg2: String)(F: => T): func2[T]
```

Thanks

Comment: Following Scala conventions, in `F: => T` the argument should be lowercase: `f: => T` not to confuse it with a type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`F` is the argument name; `=> T` means it's a *by-name parameter*. It's basically equivalent to `() => T` with some syntactic sugar:

1. When invoking this method, the argument will have type `T` and will automatically be turned into `() => T`:

   ```
   func1[String](0, x)(x + x) ===> func1[String](0, x)(() => x + x)
   ```
2. When implementing this method, each use of `F` turns into `F()`. So the value of type `T` will be recalculated each time.

Obviously, this is useful in one of two cases:

1. if `F` may not be needed;
2. if the value returned by `F` may change between different invocations.

Comment: It also allows you to add a curly brace block as a function argument to your method, without requiring a lambda variable. You can use this to simulate the syntax of a 'while' loop. I personally used it in some benchmarking stuff: `benchmarkTime(100) { someExpensiveFunction() }` (where `100` would be the number of times to run the benchmark)